# Validade if OWL instance is being used at least once by a property (in the range or domain of a property)

Tags: owl, inference

Looking at the example below. I have a class Objective. The idea is to validate if an objective is connected to another via the object property causeEffect. The instances (a to d) are connected as follows: a -> b, b -> c. I want the reasoner to warn me about instance d, since it is not connected to any other objective. Is this possible in OWL?

Right now, my solution identifies c as an objective (I'm not using the range/domain of the property), the others are manually asserted as Objectives. I used an inverse property to define that the Objective is equivalent to "(causeEffect min 1 Objective) OR (isAffectedBy min 1 Objective)". Any ideas?

Object Properties

```
<!-- myOnt#causeEffect -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="myOnt#causeEffect">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="myOnt#isAffectedBy"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- myOnt#isAffectedBy -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="myOnt#isAffectedBy"/>
```

Classes

```
<!-- myOnt#Objective -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="myOnt#Objective">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="myOnt#causeEffect"/>
                    <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
                    <owl:onClass rdf:resource="myOnt#Objective"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="myOnt#isAffectedBy"/>
                    <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
                    <owl:onClass rdf:resource="myOnt#Objective"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:unionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

Individuals

```
<!-- myOnt#a -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="myOnt#a">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="myOnt#Objective"/>
    <untitled-ontology-87:causeEffect rdf:resource="myOnt#b"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- myOnt#b -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="myOnt#b">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="myOnt#Objective"/>
    <untitled-ontology-87:causeEffect rdf:resource="myOnt#c"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- myOnt#c -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="myOnt#c"/>



<!-- myOnt#d -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="myOnt#d">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="myOnt#Objective"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OWL follows the Open World Assumption, so I'd say no, sometimes it's possible to "close the world", but it is mostly cumbersome and sometimes even impossible - for your task you should use some kind of constraint language, e.g. SHACL besides your ontology - this is a common approach nowadays.

Comment: if you try "to close the world" adding your instances as equivalentClass to Thing, at least you can see which instances are not participating in domain or range of properties in the list of individuals of Thing after running the reasoner